# django how to replace the logo title of 'django administrator'

Tags: django, django-admin, django-staticfiles

my purpose is to remove the title of  "Django administration" with yellow color in every admin page like the following screen, please help. thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the default template named base_site.html to your template directory.
you can find the default template path by running the command:

```
python -c "import django,os; print(os.path.join(django.__path__[0], 'contrib/admin/templates/admin/base_site.html'))"
```

If your template directory named "templates", you should copy base_site.html to templates/admin/base_site.html

Then edit the file and replace `{{ site_header|default:_('Django administration') }}`

See the document
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial07/#customizing-your-project-s-templates

Comment: Thanks Feng! your kindness is very much useful. Currently I replace it with the company logo.

Answer (score -1):

For do that you can type `./manage.py collectstatic` that will copy all the css files to a folder so you can edit it as you want